# Why does System.Data.DataTable work as an ItemsSource, and how can I write my own class that does the same?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I'm writing a fancy business-logic class that's essentially a table with an unknown number of columns, constructed dynamically, which includes various methods for validation, data processing  etc.

It's an `IEnumerable` of specialized row objects, which allow access to their columns through a `BusinessData this[string columnName] { get { ... } }` accessor. Almost like a `DataTable`.

I'd like to be able to data-bind it to a WPF `DataGrid`, so I want to write the following:

```
 dataGrid1.ItemsSource = myFancyMemoryTable;
```

But, of course, it won't work, because the `DataGrid` will bind itself to the public properties of my row objects, and not to the columns that contain the business data. How do I get the behavior I want from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot specifically track down where the properties are retrieved for `DataTables`/`DataRows` but if you implement [`ITypedList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.itypedlist.aspx) on your source collection that should work.